# git fetch is unable to update local ref

Tags: git, heroku

I am trying to fetch from a staging environment on Heroku, so I can see what code is currently on staging, and I can't seem to do this.

```
$ git fetch --all
Fetching origin
Fetching staging
Fetching repositoryerror: Ref refs/remotes/heroku/master is at 10b0cb58d32cee52d904af489943089f57268bb5 but expected 0119065aba7da6103c516efa7a24e7d83da45676
From heroku.personal:staging-app
! 0119065..ab29b87  master     -> heroku/master  (unable to update local ref)
, done.
error: Could not fetch staging
```

I'm not sure how to fetch staging. I have the same issue for my production environment. Fetching from origin works fine. I've tried `git fetch staging -f`, as well.